# How to get selected column value when click on item in gridview?

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener

I created a grid view in my apps and I would like to get value from my array after clicked on selected item.

Now I can get a whole list of my value, but how can I get selected item value? Example like merchant_id?

Now I getting whole array value like this.
[image]

```
private fun handleJson(jsonString: String?) {
       val jsonArray = JSONArray(jsonString)
       var list = ArrayList<Merchant>()

       var x = 0
       while (x < jsonArray.length()){
           var jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(x)

           list.add(Merchant(
                   jsonObject.getInt("merchant_id"),
                   jsonObject.getString("name"),
                   jsonObject.getString("address"),


           ))
           x++
       }

       val adapter = MerchantAdapter(this,list)
       lv_merchant_list.adapter = adapter


       var listView = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.lv_merchant_list)


       listView.setOnItemClickListener{ parent, view, position, id ->

           Toast.makeText(this, "You Clicked:"+" "+adapter.getItem(position),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
       }
   }
```

How can I enhance in adapter.getItem(position) to something like adapter.getItem(position(i)) to get merchant ID?

Comment: if `adapter.getItem(position)` returns your merchant object, why cant you just go with `adapter.getItem(position).merchant_id`? Or Im missing something

Comment: if applied adapter.getItem(position).merchant_id, it will show unresolve reference merchant_id.

Comment: sure, cast it to merchant or work with your list -> `list[position].merchant_id`, be careful as your list starts with 0 and I dont remember if returned position starts with 1 or 0 aswell

Comment: thanks P.Juni, u alert me on this. Finally I solved by using sample code as below:-** Toast.makeText(this, "You Clicked:"+""+list[position].merchant_id,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show() }**

Comment: so did it helped with this list ?

Comment: Yes, u are right. Thanks for your help. Please post your answer and I will mark it accordingly. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work on your `list` which you provided for the adapter.

So replace `adapter.getItem(position)` with simple `list[position].merchant_id`, so then you can retrieve any field from the picked item from the list.